# Where should I attach the ground wire in a recessed light?

Tags: grounding, recessed-lighting

I have a recessed can light on the 1st floor with e26 light bulb (Below are pictures) and want to upgrade to LED. I have the LED with metal box and have a green grounded wire. I do not see a place to attach the grounded wire in the can. Any suggestions on how to ground?

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you use one of those pop-in conversion kits that screws to the E26 base you won't need to think about the ground, btw.

Comment: @crip659 remember to make that an answer not just a comment, my comment was a redirect

Comment: @KMJ the "kit that screws to the E26 base" I've seen (with a metallic surround) most certainly do also have a separate ground wire to be attached to the can. And every can I've been in had a suitable screw somewhere. If the entire exposed part is plastic then a ground may not be needed.

Comment: @Ecnerwal I have one of those kits from GE in my basement right now new in box, no ground wire. It has a screw in base that goes to a two pin connector, the actual light with trim ring, and that's it. Not a ground to be found, it is basically just a replacement for a light bulb. Here's an example similar one: https://www.homedepot.com/p/Commercial-Electric-4-in-New-Construction-or-Remodel-White-Integrated-LED-Recessed-Light-Trim-with-Color-Changing-Technology-4-Pack-NS01dA09ER2-259/314018770

Comment: @crip659 -- normally, you'd be on the right track, but that suggestion wouldn't work for the OP because their can isn't grounded either (note the AC cable or flex conduit extending into the can with no sign of a terminating fitting)

Comment: @Charles is there a box on the outside of the fixture can, or just an armored cable running directly into the can?

Comment: Please expand on "LED with metal box". It's unclear whether this kit is suitable for just placing inside a regular can fixture. The kit may have no exposed metal parts, and therefore not require grounding. The can is already grounded by means of its attachment to its junction box.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel This is the can light model I have [link](https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00084WC18/ref=ox_sc_act_title_1?smid=A1FOIQJS3IQE59&psc=1). Does connecting the ground to the screw in the photo work as suggested by crip659 still work or should we use the Arlington 38RASTG as suggested

Comment: @Charles -- you should be able to use the screw, apologies for the confusion on my end

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Np, at all. Thank you for your viewpoints and responses.